# Using delegate methods to save a custom cell textfield

Tags: ios, delegates, textfield, uitableview

I am having trouble understanding how to use delegate methods to save the text value from a textfield which is contained in a table cell. I am using a separate .xib file, which contains the textfield, for the table cell. Below is code for using cellForRowAt indexpath, but I'm not sure how to communicate between the textfield and the the swift file that contains this code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let currentCellDescriptor = getCellDescriptorForIndexPath(indexPath)
    if currentCellDescriptor["cellIdentifier"] as! String == "idEntranceFee" {
        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField!) {

         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to handle this problem.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "PostsCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PostsCell")
        postsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostsCell") as! PostsCell
        let song = album.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSArray
        let songName = song[0] as? String
        postsCell.titleLabel.text = songName
return postsCell
    }
```

This is what my postsCell file looks like.

```
class PostsCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel : UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bodyLabel : UILabel!
}
```

Your question is a little vague but this should help you out. Comment back if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You must set a delegate for each UITextfield in the ViewController, in your case in each UITableViewCell.

```
textField.delegate = self
```

Then implement UITextFieldDelegate in your ViewContoller:

```
extension YourViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
  func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

  }
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath  indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

  }
}
```